# Problem populating URL from a DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've the URLs stored in a Data Extension, and want to print them. Here's what I've done;

Below is the lookup I'm using.

```
%%= Lookup('Table', 'URL2', 'LANGUAGE_COUNTRY', Lowercase(@LANGUAGE_COUNTRY)) =%%
```

But it gives an HTTP 400 error.

Using the field LANGUAGE_COUNTRY, I'm able to localize the text using a different DE, with the following lookup;

```
%%= Lookup('Text_Table', 'TEXT1', 'LANGUAGE_COUNTRY', Lowercase(@LANGUAGE_COUNTRY)) =%%
```

So I doubt that there's something wrong with the lookup I'm using,

Can anyone help me on that? And if I haven't provided enough information, please let me know and I'll edit the question.

edit: Here's the pastebin of a portion of the code, http://pastebin.com/apvBw1gb

The values of the url are very much like the difference between https ://www.google.nl/ and https ://www.google.fr/

So the https://www.google.%%LANGUAGE_COUNTRY%% can be one of the two examples above.

Comment: Could you add the complete code? Are there any parameters in your URL?

Comment: I've edited the question, I didn't have enough rep to post more than 2 urls in it, so please ignore the spaces after the https://

Comment: I would do the following, use a variable and assign the value of the lookup, then display the content of the variable as a text in your HTML. That should give you some idea of what is happening.   Then use the variable after in href line.

Comment: Using a variable can definitely work, but is not an ideal solution since there'll be lot of emails & a lot of links in them. Wrapping the lookup with a redirectto function will work. I'll submit an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wrapped the lookups of the links with RedirectTo() function, and that was it!

```
%%= RedirectTo(Lookup('Table', 'URL2', 'LANGUAGE_COUNTRY', Lowercase(@LANGUAGE_COUNTRY))) =%%
```